# Add "Search the Internet" to the Windows 7 Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

How do I add "Search the Internet" to the Windows 7 Start Menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone seems to be interested in installing some registry edit. I prefer the Group Policy change.

1. From the Start menu, type **Edit group policy** and press Enter.
2. Expand **Administrative Templates** in the left navigation pane.
3. Select **Start Menu and Taskbar** in the left navigation pane.
4. In the main window, double-click **Add Search Internet link to Start Menu**.
5. Choose **Enabled** and click OK.
6. Exit the Group Policy Editor.

There are screenshots and information on alternative methods at [Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/557-start-menu-add-search-internet-link.html).